Common cathode LCD display, can a common anode LCD be used instead?
I have a GPS which uses a common cathode LCD and I need to replace it as some segments stopped working but unfortunately I haven't found anywhere I can buy it as this version is mass produced and you have to buy a bunch of them.
The common anode version is easily found so my question is if there's a way to use a common anode version.

The part number are LFD027AG-10 or the LFD028AAG-104 but unfortunately I can't find a place where to buy them.

The short answer is yes, it’s not technically impossible but the long answer is that we’ll need a lot more to go on.  Do you have a part number for the display you want to replace?

You should also consider if it is the display that has failed or another component. A single digit not working would suggest it is a different component (in the circuit that drives that digit). If it were a single segment, I'd be more confident of a new display fixing the fault.

That's not even a LCD, they don't have anodes and cathodes, just commons and segments.
That's a LED display, and there are all sorts of different types of modules available. If you can't find a suitable all-in-one module, you can always use individual 7-segment digits and build a PCB with enough digits.

Not as a drop-in replacement connected in a commercial product's PCB, no.
It'd need a significant changes to the circuit and that's beyond practical modifications to a compact product like the GPS unit.

Here (Digi-Key) are 14 common cathode potential replacements. The pinout and voltage drop should be verified. These can be purchased as single digits but an adapter board would be necessary.

